# How to calculate the Kinect physical position, and display it in a game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect, oculus

I'm doing an internship, in which I'm working on a rehabilitation game for amputated people (the goal is to help diminishing phantom pain).

The game is using a Kinect and an Oculus Rift, and developed on Unity3D. A virtual avatar is displayed in the Oculus as in a FPS and follow the movement of the user thanks to the Kinect. The goal being that the person with a missing limb can see himself with a full body. (AR is added later)

It is already kind of functional, but I have to improve the calibration. For that, I need to place in the virtual world a marker where the Kinect physically stands to allow the user to fix it when wearing the Oculus.

I didn't find clear enough documentation (for me at least) about the structures of the data send by the Kinect. I thing I should find the rotation of the user's body according to the Kinect, and use it to place the marker. For example, if the user is 45° from facing directly the Kinect, I should place the marker at -45° from the line of sight of the Oculus. Easy to say, but I'm not sure how to retrieve this information from the Kinect data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn785530.aspx), the kinect is located at the origin. I assume that you where able to read the users position from the kinect, since you say that you placed the avatar properly.

If the avatar is indeed placed by the kinect, then just put your maker in (0, 0, 0) and that should be the kinect's position

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yep, that was I thought, but in fact it is the Oculus that has been placed at the point 0,0,0 inside the game. I did not do it, it was already done before I started working on this project.

Comment: Then I am affraid that this depends of your code. But you can use this info. The kinect is going to assume it is placed in 0, 0, 0 and send data accordingly. There must be a place in your code where the coordinates sent by the kinect are transformed to match the oculus. Find this place to know how a point from the kinect is transformed. Then apply the same function to (0, 0, 0) to know where you must place it in your coordinate system

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I see that this is you first question. If you consider that this closes the topic, you can **accept the answer** (see [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about why and how). Otherwise you can leave it as is if you expect some more answers